# Assert in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automation, assert

[image]

---

I have a requirement where I have to assert date and time stamp.

### How do i do that using python selenium

### The requirement is, i fill the form and submit it and once i submit, it is submitted successfully and when i view it, it displays a label text field called "date added" : and date/time displayed.

### Now in my automation - i want to assert this date/time, to make sure it is not blank ( i want to validate it using assert. This date / time will be different for different records)

for reference I have attached the both the screenshot
[image: en]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below solution :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")
element=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//strong[@class='ng-binding ng-scope']")
print element.text

if(len(element.text) == 0): 
    print ("Yes") 
else : 
    print ("No")
```